# How to add the color image stream on the skeleton view C#

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm working in the skeleton basics sample WPF application C# found in the kinect tool kit examples, the skeleton now appears on the image of the main window.xaml but the rest of the image is black so just the skeleton in green, I want to view both the skeleton and the RGB image stream on form, in which the image of the person standing infront of the kinect appears and the skeleton is drawn on the same image, so how can i do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorials](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Getting-started-with-Kinect-development-quickly-with-the-Kinect-for-Windows-Quickstart-Series). The guy explains very well how to start developing for Kinect